# disable Alt+Super workspace switcher

Tags: gnome, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome-shell

How can I disable Alt+Super+Left/Right from switching workspace in gnome-shell?

If I go into Keyboard settings there is no options

I am using latest GNOME version on Arch Linux.
I am on Xorg.

Comment: Strange that there are no options in keyboard settingsm but then Gnome seems intent on removing everything remotely useful these days. Can you find the relevant setting in `dconf-editor`? Try searching for "workspace" for example.

Comment: thanks @terdon for the tip; I have already watched there but sketchily... for story in the answer below

Answer (score 1):

Solution can be achieved using graphical front-end **dconf-editor** or directly using coherent terminal commands:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-left "['<Control><Alt>Left']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-right "['<Control><Alt>Right']"
```

In this way, I achieve my goal: disabling *Alt+Super* combinations, while leaving *Ctrl+Alt* ones functional

**But... why is this issue so *difficult* to solve?**
Well, it is a gnome defect, since Gnome's Settings (Settings → Keyboard → Shortcut) does not show multiple shortcuts

*in this case, by default, left workspace switching can be done with both: <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd> or <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> or <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> but shortcut settings show only the first one! An issue **[1]** that has already been opened in the upstream bug-tracker, years ago.*

---

**[1]** https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-control-center/-/issues/620